# 3D vector with quiver remains static

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, 3d

I got the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.quiver(0,0,0,10, 0, 0, pivot='tail')

ax.set_xlim3d(-2, 5)
ax.set_ylim3d(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim3d(-2, 2)

plt.grid()
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Running this never changes the length of the vector in the x-direction. It seems to be stuck by 1. Any idea how I could draw the vector r = (10,0,0)?
I also tried to use scale, scale_units, and angles but without success. It just kept on complaining that these attributes do not exist.
FYI, this is only a MWE.

Comment: When running your code I see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMC0y.png). The arrow is cut, because of the chosen xlim. But one can see that it would go up to 10. Choosing other limits like `ax.set_xlim3d(-2, 12)` would be more useful I guess.

Comment: I was just playing around with the limits. It didn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Then I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: When I change the end position of the vector in x, it always draws a vector that ends at 1.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it doesn't occur when I run the code (as seen from the image linked above). So you will need to provide more information, e.g. what versions you are using etc, to help someone help you.

Comment: Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
matplotlib version '1.5.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed three years ago via https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5458, which means it'll work as expected in matplotlib >= 2.0.
Also see [API changes in 2.0](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/api_changes.html#new-defaults-for-3d-quiver-function-in-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-py) where it says

> The 3D quiver function previously normalized the arrows to be the same length, which makes it unusable for situations where the arrows should be different lengths and does not match the behavior of the 2D function. This normalization behavior is now controlled with the normalize keyword, which defaults to False.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work now. When I ran the module with python3 it used an older version of matplotlib as when I used python2.7,. Any idea why?

Comment: No, I can't know how you installed your packages.